# Value something above something/ value something over something

Tags: word-choice

Which of the 2 is best?

> He values her **above** all others.
>   He values her **over** all others.

I can't tell which sounds better and looking up in dictionaries amounted to nothing at least the ones I have looked at.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google Books claims 35 written instances of [He values her above...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22He+values+her+above%22), but only one instance of [He values her over...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22He+values+her+over%22) It's just a stylistic choice, where any claimed distinction is just nit-picking for the sake of it, but obviously *most* writers make the same choice.

Answer (score 4):

In that particular case (talking about a living creature) "above" would sound "warmer", though both are grammatically correct.

Comment: This answer fits my sense. "Above all" is the more common -- https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=above+all%2C+over+all&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3 --  and the more commonly used phrase in literary language (see Shakespeare) and religious language (e.g. the Bible)  -- "over all" might be slightly more associated with a straight valuation vs. a romantic / philosophical / moral / spiritual statement in "above all." But both can be used for both....

Comment: Yes, "straight valuation" is the connotation I have for "over" as well.  I tried to figure out how to express that, but couldn't come up with anything.  I should have gone the other way:  "above" is emotional, "over" is unemotional.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples

> He values her **above** all others.

is the better choice.  One way to tell, is to look at the opposite

> He values her **above** all others.
>   He values her **below** all others.
>
> He values her **over** all others.
>   He values her **under** all others.

The last sentence is not quite right.